# Vim: How to set preference for custom file types?

Tags: vim, file-types

I can set the custom filetype settings for the know file types using the `*.vim` files in ftplugin directory, e.g. c.vim for (c, cpp, h, hxx), python.vim etc.

But I want to set the file types for the custom file extension like `*.text`, `*.letter`, `*.journal` etc. I tried using text.vim and so on but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [autocommands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html). Add a line for each custom file extension in your `.vimrc`:

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.ext setfiletype ext
```

Then you can specify settings for `.ext` files in `ftplugin/ext.vim`.

*PS: Note that autocommands must be defined inside an augroup.*

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `:h new-filetype`.

Comment: Your answer is great but mrucci gave a direct solution.

Comment: Direct, indeed. But incomplete. There exist files dedicated to filetype detection.