# Effectively manage sets of Vim settings

Tags: vim, vimrc

Is there any effective way to manage multiple sets of Vim configuration?

I need this because I need different sets of configuration for different types of work. It depends a lot whether I'm writing a text or programming in Python. Things like autoindentation, syntax highlighting, functions of key combinations etc. need to be different.

Imagine if you had multiple `.vimrc` files and you only needed to change your Vim *mode* (via a shortcut) to switch between them. That's what I want, except I'd rather have it all in one `.vimrc` file (I'd have it organized well, I use folding). Different sections of the file would correspond to different sets of configuration.

I've googled around but couldn't find the solution (perhaps due to bad search query phrasing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim: How to set preference for custom file types?](http://superuser.com/questions/157252/vim-how-to-set-preference-for-custom-file-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many settings (like indentation) are bound to *filetypes*, anyway. You can also define *buffer-local* mappings and commands, so several pieces of your requirements just require consistent use of built-in abstractions (read `:help ftplugin`).

For global stuff, I would recommend to keep the differences to an absolute minimum, as this prevents building up muscle memory and efficient editing "without thinking". There are several possible implementations to pass a discriminating flag to Vim when launching:

1. separate `.vimrc` via `$ vim -u {vimrc}`. But as you want to keep everything in one file, the following are better:
2. via variable: `$ vim --cmd "let pluginmode='python'"`, then use `if g:pluginmode ==# 'python' ... else ...` inside your .vimrc.
3. via environment variable `$ PLUGINMODE=python vim`, then use `if $PLUGINMODE ...`

#### Plugins

Many plugins use the canonical `g:loaded_{pluginname}` inclusion guard, with which you can enable / disable them in your `~/.vimrc`. Also, if you use a plugin manager, you can probably put the `Bundle ...` commands inside conditionals.

#### Dynamic mode switch

All of the above assumes you quit and restart Vim for a change in modes. If you want to do this on the fly, that's a lot more effort, and it will be hard to get rid of previous commands / mappings completely.